# Determine if $T$ is a Linear Transformation or Not

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that

$$
T\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x-y\\
x+y \\
2x
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I tried multiplying with a scalar as follows

$$
T \left\{\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y \\
     \end{pmatrix}\right\} 
 =T\begin{pmatrix}
    \alpha x\\
   \alpha y \\
     \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
   \alpha x- \alpha y\\
    \alpha x+\alpha y \\
2\alpha x
     \end{pmatrix}
= \alpha \begin{pmatrix}
    x-y\\
    x+y \\
2x
     \end{pmatrix}
 =\alpha T\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y \\
     \end{pmatrix}
$$

Is the above correct?

And I don't know how to show the addition part.

Comment: You also need to check
$$
T(x_1 + x_2) = T(x_1) + T(x_2)
$$

Comment: Yes that's what I want to know how

Comment: @S.Dan You just use the definition of $T$ on the left-hand side to get one $3$-dimensional vector. You use the definition twice on the right-hand side to get a sum of two $3$-dimensional vectors. Now see if you can justify putting an equals sign between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part for the multiplication is correct.

For the addition, consider two different vectors 
$V_1=\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y \\
\end{pmatrix}$
and 
$V_2=\begin{pmatrix}
u\\
v \\
\end{pmatrix}$
and show that 
$$T(V_1+V_2)=T(V_1)+T(V_2)$$

Comment: Oh got it - it is a transformation. Thanks!

Comment: @S.Dan: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is, for the addition part consider

$$
T\begin{pmatrix}
     x + x'\\
   y + y'\\
     \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
    (x- y) + (x'-y')\\
    (x+y) + (x' + y') \\
2x + 2x'
     \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
    x-y\\
    x+y \\
2x
     \end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{pmatrix}
    x'-y'\\
    x'+y' \\
2x'
     \end{pmatrix}
 = T\begin{pmatrix}
    x\\
    y \\
     \end{pmatrix}+T\begin{pmatrix}
    x'\\
    y' \\
     \end{pmatrix}
$$